# (Laravel) Can I pass a dropdown value directly into a controller method?

Tags: laravel, methods, controller

All I want is to pass a dropdown value directly to my controller method. Is there any possible ways to do this or are there any documentations or tutorials on how to do this? By the way, I'm using Laravel 5.7. Any comments that might help me solve this problem will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is the code for my dropdown.

```
<form  method="POST" id="year" name="year">
              <select name="year">
                    <option class="dropdown-item" selected name="years" disabled>--Select Year--</option>
                 <?php 
                    $start = "2017";
                    $end = (int)date("Y");                
                       for($i=$start; $i<=$end; $i++){                  
                          echo '<option class="dropdown-item" value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
                       }
                 ?>                          
             </select>                  
   </form>
```

This is the method in my controller where I want to pass the dropdown value.

```
public function resolution_time_of_calls(){         

        //declarations            
        $arr_val = array();
        $arr_val1 = array();
        $arr_val2 = array();
        $arr_monthname = array();
        $arr_monthInt = array();               

        //SELECTING MONTHS  
        $quer = DB::select("SELECT MONTH(DATE_ADD(T.Created, INTERVAL 8 HOUR)) AS MonthInt
            ,monthname(DATE_ADD(T.Created, INTERVAL 8 HOUR)) AS Month
            ,year(DATE_ADD(T.Created, INTERVAL 8 HOUR)) AS Year               
            FROM rtdb.Tickets T
            LEFT JOIN rtdb.ObjectCustomFieldValues O ON O.ObjectId=T.EffectiveId 
            AND O.CustomField=15 AND O.ObjectType='RT::Ticket' AND O.Disabled=0
            WHERE T.Status!='Deleted' AND T.IsMerged IS NULL AND T.Type='ticket'
            AND year(DATE_ADD(T.Created, INTERVAL 8 HOUR))= 2018
            GROUP BY Month,MonthInt,Year Order by MonthInt asc
            ");   
        $chart = new SampleChart;                            
        $chart->title('Resolution Time of Calls');                 
        foreach($quer as $query){
            array_push($arr_monthname, $query->Month.", ".$query->Year);  
            array_push($arr_monthInt, $query->MonthInt);   
        }                     
        $chart->labels($arr_monthname); 

        ///////////////////// TOTAL, AVERAGE,MAXIMUM Query  ////////////////////
        foreach($arr_monthInt as $month){
            $sql = DB::select("SELECT MONTH(DATE_ADD(T.Created, INTERVAL 8 HOUR)) AS MonthInt

                ,AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,T.Created,O.Created)) AS AVG   
                ,MAX(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,T.Created,O.Created)) AS MAX               
                FROM rtdb.Tickets T
                LEFT JOIN rtdb.ObjectCustomFieldValues O ON O.ObjectId=T.EffectiveId 
                AND O.CustomField=15 AND O.ObjectType='RT::Ticket' AND O.Disabled=0
                WHERE T.Status!='Deleted' AND T.IsMerged IS NULL AND T.Type='ticket'
                AND year(DATE_ADD(T.Created, INTERVAL 8 HOUR))= 2018                    
                GROUP BY MonthInt Order by MonthInt asc");
        }
        foreach($sql as $value){

            array_push($arr_val1, $value->AVG );
            array_push($arr_val2, $value->MAX );
        }

        $chart->dataset('Average Hours', 'bar', $arr_val1)->backgroundcolor('#00833E');   
        $chart->dataset('Maximum Hours', 'bar', $arr_val2)->backgroundcolor('#AF1D2D');   
        $chart->height(600);


    return view('resolution_time_of_calls',['chart'=>$chart]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Ajax as there is no submit button in your form. The ajax call will get executed once you select any option (i.e., on change event)

```
$(document).on('change', '#year', function () {

    $.ajax({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        url: YOUR_URL,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#year").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Success==>', data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error==>', data);
        }
    });
});
```

In your controller, you can check using `$request->all()`.

Comment: I added the request->all() in my controller and there is this error.  Undefined variable: request

Comment: replace this line:  public function resolution_time_of_calls(Request $request){

Comment: Did you replaced the URL?

Comment: yeah i put `resolution_time_of_calls`

Comment: The variable "YOUR_URL" will get replaced with your actual route to that function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188570/discussion-between-charlie-matanguihan-and-mr-gandhi).